# cabal-install failed to install a version that depends on the same version

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm completely new to Haskell and I'm trying to replicate the [code.world](https://code.world/) environment locally, so I need to install [`codeworld-api`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codeworld-api) so that I can `import CodeWorld`. The problem is that when I run `cabal install codeworld-api`, it fails, and the following errors occur:

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
codeworld-api-0.7.0-JVbla7smM91CfqAXV0vVqz depends on codeworld-api-0.7.0
which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.23.1-Z8xb2tkymYIClPofvAOw3 failed during the configure
step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
haskell-src-meta-0.8.7-GrcU6O1imfWLP5hRNzLFKK depends on
haskell-src-meta-0.8.7 which failed to install.
haskell-tests-0.1.0.0-IkWvWTmkph53PXtIhZGNWg depends on haskell-tests-0.1.0.0
which failed to install.
reflex-0.8.1.0-5XPDDia7wXx4bpQRZBxYDv depends on reflex-0.8.1.0 which failed
to install.
```

I also tried to add `codeworld-api` in the `build-depends` section in `.cabal`, but nothing changes.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310179/cabal-fails-to-install-dependencies-but-can-install-them-if-asked-directly), but `--allow-newer` also does nothing.

I tried, with no success:

- `cabal update`
- `cabal install Cabal cabal-install`
- `cabal new-install codeworld-api`
- `cabal new-build`

`codeworld-api` also doesn't show up in `ghc-pkg list`.

I have no idea what's happening...

---

**Platform info**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- cabal-install version 2.4.0.0
- Cabal library version 2.4.0.1
- ghc version 8.6.5
- Packages installed from `apt`:

  - ghc
  - ghc-doc
  - cabal-install

Comment: I think the actual issue is further up the output - look if you can find the reason any of these packages failed - it's probably a missing dependency (dev-library)

Comment: @Carsten, I've added a list of packages that I installed (from `apt`). Am I missing something?